# JavaScript: Not able to get tagName on click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get `tagName` of any element inside the iframe `onclick`. However, I'm not being able to do that. I'm new to JavaScript. Where am I wrong?

```
<div class="flex-child green">
    <p id="a">You clicked on: </p>
    <iframe
      id="zzz"
      srcdoc="<html><h1>hello</h1><button>click me!</button></html>"
      width="500"
      height="500"
      onload="clickfn()"
    ></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function clickfn() {
    x = document.getElementById("zzz").target.tagName;
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = x;
  }
</script>

<style>
  .flex-container {
    display: flex;
  }

  .flex-child.green {
    flex: 1;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: onclick on the parent has no insight on what you clicked inside the iframe.

Comment: If you need to access the content inside an iframe (and it only works for **same origin iframes**), then you need to access the `window` object of the iframed page using the `contentWindow` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow

Comment: And if you want to actually listen to the click event from an iframe (based on the name of your function but you're listening to the `onload` event, so it's not clear what you're trying to do), then it is the iframed page responsibility to emit that event as a [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) instead, which the parent page will listen using the `onMessage` event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the shown code (using `srcdoc`) you should be able to attach the event listener to the `contentWindow` of the `iframe`:

```js
document.getElementById("zzz").addEventListener('load', iframeLoaded)

function iframeLoaded() {
  document.getElementById("zzz").contentWindow.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = e.target.tagName;
  })
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-child.green {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-child green">
  <p id="a">You clicked on: </p>
  <iframe id="zzz" srcdoc="<html><h1>hello</h1><button>click me!</button></html>" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
</div>
```

Whether this works or not depends on the security headers send by the server, here on StackOverflow it does not work. On [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/02vmwn5g/) it works.